# CSS cursor pointer flicker once and then back to default

Tags: css

I am experience a weird behaviour in both Google Chrome and Safari in OSX.

The cursor is changing to the pointer quickly, and then back to the default one when hovering links and elements where I have set cursor: pointer in the css.

I haven't been able to reproduce it on any other site of mine so just gonna drop the url here: http://stage.lagenheter24.se

Why is this happening? And how can I solve it? I have tried to set following without any result:

```
a { cursor: pointer !important; }
```

Comment: i don't see any problems on your page. my cursor was always pointer !

Comment: Which HTML element is experiencing the issue?

Comment: @MohammadYekta really!? Which browser are you using on what OS?

Comment: @AdamMilecki every link and the smaller images in the grid.

Comment: Everything is working fine on my end.

Comment: Google chrome latest version on Windows 10 :-)

Comment: I haven't tested Safari but all the links seem to be working for me in Chrome v45.

Comment: I tried restart the computer, but that did not work. However it worked like a charm today.. And the problem was visible in both Chrome and Safari, so nothing browser specific. No idea what exactly happened.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't believe you need to restart your computer for this. The issue is actually when Photoshop is open at the same time as your web browser. For some reason this creates the issue. I imagine it has something to do with Adobe and Apple not playing nice. If you close photoshop the issue should resolve. Rebooting the computer only appears to work because you likely closed your programs before doing so.

Comment: Photoshop causes all sorts of curser flicker oddities across the entire OS when it is open(Mac OS).  They really need to get this fixed. It even makes the curser freak out in illustrator.. solid work adobe.

Comment: I also had this issue, and I did just have Photoshop open for the first time in a while. However, quitting Photoshop did not solve the issue for me.

Comment: Wow this absolutely was the issue for me - more specifically I found I'd left the color picker tool open - closing that tool window fixed it without having to close Photoshop altogether.

Comment: Lol, this has been an issue for me for so long I just accepted it as some inherent Chrome bug and moved on.   PS is always open in the background so I never put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: In my case it was Photoshop too. This is ridiculous, spent so much time trying to debug my code and removing everything until I was left with a blank page with one `a` tag without any CSS and it still didn't work :'-)

Comment: Wow, spent almost 3 hours on this! Photoshop was open in my case as well. Thanks a lot, wonder how you figured this out.

Comment: That's absurd. I was trying to hide my cursor and it would keep reappearing. It seems it was some other window behind my current browser, seriously. Ouch, RIP my time

Comment: lol thats so wild. i was losing my mind then read this and looked at my dock...chrome, photoshop. thank youu

Comment: YEP - this is the correct answer!! strange

Comment: 2021 and It was Photoshop in my case as well. And it also explains why most of the clients or project managers almost never report such an issue :)

Comment: I did change the correct answer to this one now 2022, as this seems to be the more correct one even though a reboot did solve the issue. But that is just because Photoshop was closed as well during reboot.

Comment: Can confirm. Same issue occured for me while developing on web and Photoshop was open.

Comment: Wow this was it. I'm on macOS Ventura 13.1, with whatever the June 16, 2023 version of Photoshop Beta would be :)

Comment: 2023 and Photoshop is still the culprit - wow.

Answer (score 54):

This sounds like a ridiculous answer but I had a similar issue on Mac OSX (any browser).
I've noticed the problem wasn't in my code but on other web pages too - like [this one](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/) and a simple system reboot solved this.

Comment: Late to the party, but can confirm. I had the same issue and tore my hair out looking for z-index problems or invalid CSS - turns out the problem was my mac. Rebooted and it worked fine.

Comment: Hilarious... the amount of time I spent tweaking CSS/HTML to try and fix this -- less hilarious. This is the correct answer :'(

Comment: Just experienced the same thing. I am working on something with a custom scripting language that renders out an HTML page and I was losing it trying to figure out why my links were acting weird! \*shakes fist\*

Comment: Well, I have been reproducing the issue on Mac OSX. The problem happened when I had a page opened on another tab with flash player activated...

Comment: I also just experienced this on macOS 10.13.5 in both Chrome 67 and Firefox 59. This answer saved me time debugging! The reboot fixed it.

Comment: As mentioned below.. just close photoshop, no need to reboot. That was enough to fix it for me.

Comment: Photoshop.  It's Photoshop.

Comment: I too didn't realise that Adobe were in the cursor hijacking business... How silly.

Comment: November 2020 Update: Yes it's still happening... MacOS Catalina v10.15.7 and Chrome 86.0.4240.198. AND I DO NOT HAVE PHOTOSHOP ! .. Opened Applications perior to the issue: iTerm2 (My suspect), Sublime Text, Thunderbird, Git's built-in GUI (Another suspect that sometimes causes some mouse issues in it's own window).

Comment: OMG, this answer was a lifesaver!! I was going nuts over what I changed, when I hadn't really changed anything :-D And yes, this is a Nov 22nd, 2020 reply too!!

Comment: My goodness! I didn't have Photoshop open. Disconnected my external monitor and my cursor problem goes away. Still works on reconnection :)

Comment: Mine was Photoshop. This was even prevent react and css events from properly firing (mouseEnter, mouseLeave, &:hover) were all not firing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the element position is changed very subtly when you hover on it, causing it to rapidly switch between hovered and unhovered state, then the CSS `cursor` is switching too.

Try giving it a position `relative` or `absolute` :)

Comment: In my case `<img class="hover-img" ...>` with CSS `.hover-img {opacity: .75; ...} .hover-img:hover {opacity: 1; ...}` image became opaque on hover at first, but then returned to semi-transparent state while I kept the mouse still over the image. On mouse movement (still hovering) it flickered rapidly. Giving it `position: relative` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

this trouble happens for me in Mozilla and Internet Explorer when cursor hover on elements which has an **float** property. so my solution is go out from float:right\left to **position:absolute** (or fixed) with adding the positions for those elements. hope solution helps you :)