# Mac browser cursor link behavior

Tags: macos, cross-browser, apple-m1, mouse-cursor

I noticed the strangest behavior on my Mac (macOS Big Sur 11.6, Apple M1) in any browser (Firefox 96.0, Chrome 97.0.4692.71).

When my cursor hovers over a link, it turns into a hand for an instant and goes back to an arrow straight away. It's like it wants to show the correct cursor, and then overwrites it.
Even having an `!important` to the CSS property of a link doesn't change this behavior.

Does anyone have an idea how to change this?

A video of the behavior, W3C page is used via WeTransfer:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/37b8e4a034cbeee674fb480bf055144f20220114093334/77efdb

On an other computer (macOS Big Sur 11.2, Intel Core) I don't have this weird behavior.
I can't find anything decent online about this, my apologies if it's already mentioned somewhere.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852350/css-cursor-pointer-flicker-once-and-then-back-to-default/40995591

Comment: Curious, that stackoverflow issue says they had to reboot their system (which would probably have worked), but in the meantime it has solved itself it seems..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours the behavior was gone.

An entire reboot would probably have solved it too (I only shut down the browsers and even upgraded them, but even that didn't change the behavior).

As Jaime S mentioned, this issue also mentions it [CSS cursor pointer flicker once and then back to default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852350/8836686)

Comment: hard to believe, but after reboot, it works ! thanks a lot!